# New url key is not working for product after update in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite, category-products

I have product XYZ and URL key for this product is `www.mysite.com/xyz`

I have updated the value of URL key product from **xyz** to **xyz-new**.

When I try to access url `www.mysite.com/xyz-new`. It gives me 404 error.

I have noticed that product  `url_key` is updated correctly, but `url_path` is not updating.

Is this known issue in magento 2.1.x?

Any solution for this?

Comment: Have update manually?

Comment: yes. I have edited a product from backend and updated it manually for url key..

Comment: have you tried after reindex

Comment: yes ... I have already did this.. but it doesnt work for me

Comment: make sure xyz- new it's not taking space between

Comment: no its not with space ... it is  xyz-new

Comment: did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `www.mysite.com/xyz-new.html`

If not working check the Product URL suffix in

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Product URL Suffix

Try clearing cache.

Comment: This field is  blank on my site... there is no value

Comment: I hope you did Reindex

Comment: yes ... I have already did this

Comment: Check db if URL rewrites updated. If not updated then take backup of url-rewrite table. And truncate and save all the products again(if it is possible)

Comment: In db its not updated..... there are 1490 products... saving all product again is definitely  not good idea.. and not even good solution

Answer (score 0):

**url_path** is deprecated, and could safely delete its data. I tested it in my Magento 2.1.18.

You could see the deprecated statement in the [offical github comment](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9113#issuecomment-488790088)